# Lower Bounded WildCard in Java Generics

Tags: java, generics

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collection;

public class LowerBoundedWildCard {
    public static void display(Collection<? super Integer> ints, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            ints.add(i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Number> numList = new ArrayList<Number>();
        display(numList, 5); // Error
        numList.add(19.43); // Error
        }
   }
```

`List<Integer>` is more restrictive than `List<? super Integer>` because the former matches a list of type Integer only, whereas the latter matches a list of any type that is a supertype of Integer. Number is a supertype of Integer and double , then why this error is coming ??

Please help me fix the above issue.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a Number class in your package that hides the "official" one?

Comment: What are the error messages?

Answer (score 2):

I tried the code and there is no error. I can even print the list without problems:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class Test
{
    public static void display(Collection<? super Integer> ints, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            ints.add(i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Number> numList = new ArrayList<Number>();
        display(numList, 5);
        numList.add(19.43);
        System.out.println( "numList = " + numList );
    }

}
```

Output:

```
numList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 19.43]
```